# How to substitute in expression and compute it? Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have a symbolic function on Sympy, and I have a long expression involving it. For example:

```
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import Function
F = Function('F')(x) 
exp = diff(F,x,x).subs(F, x**3+x) + F**2
```

Now I would like to substitute a particular expression for the function `F`, and have it evaluate it, for example:

```
exp.subs(F,x*4)
>>>x**8 + Derivative(x**4, (x, 2))
```

However, I would like it to return `x**8+12*x**2` since this is what you get when you differentiate twice `x**4`. How can I do this?

Thanks,
Eduardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there are actions that need to be done after a substitution, you just need to "doit":

```
>>> F = Function('F')(x)
>>> exp = diff(F,x,x).subs(F, x**3+x) + F**2
>>> exp.subs(F,x*4)
16*x**2 + Derivative(x**3 + x, (x, 2))
>>> _.doit()
16*x**2 + 6*x
```

(If it can be done it will be done; but sometimes -- like with Integrals -- they will remain undone because there is no solution programmed into SymPy.)

Comment: Thanks you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.